# Xcode Unable to add test target to existing swift project - Target to be tested is grayed out

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I have an existing project that I am trying to add unit tests to.
I'm on Xcode 10.1 and project is purely in Swift.

I start by clicking on "New Target..."
In the first dialog I am able to choose the project but the dialog box for "Target to be tested" is grayed out.

I have tried to go ahead and add the test target without choosing and this results in my test bundle not being able to find my existing classes - "No such Module error"

Here is the dialog for adding the test bundle:
[image: Target to be tested grayed out]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong to prevent the this selection

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Xcode 10.2.1, with your project open, click on the diamond with a dash in it:

[image]

Then down at the bottom left of the project window click on the '+' and select "New Unit Test Target".

Comment:  Tomasz! I'll remember to use that image insertion approach!

Comment: This worked for me! Creating a new target from the file menu left my "Target to be tested" option greyed out but it was available and pre-selected when I did it this way. Thanks!